# db data send through Remote DataBase or rabimtMQ

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rabbitmq

I created two apps in node js

i: Parser (server 1)

ii: functional app with rest api's(server 2)

Each application run on different server

database(MongoDB) connection is on server 2

the main purpose of parser is to get the hardware device data and implement the protocol and send the data to database

Now i have two option to send the data from server 1 to server 2 db

1: RemoteDb

2: RabitMQ to send the data to server 2 and then save data in localDB

which one is better or any other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote DB connection is not a good approach with multiple nodes, always use any communication protocol like Redis or Raabbit MQ etc. Lets take the example

You have the parser app deployed on 3 different server nodes and the multiple iot devices is sending continuous data that need to be parsed and delivered to database. So

1. With remote db connection it will not be able to handle the data and their responses in quick time, and there are chances connection can be dropped in case of bottleneck.
2. With [redis-cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) approach it will be quickly accessible.
3. With Rabbit MQ , messages are difficult to be ack back so apply it only in place where there will be no issue if messages can be missed.

Comment: I also use redis and socket.io for sending notification and real time data display

Answer (score 1):

As always, it depends on your requirements.
 
If you'd like to only store data, means, mostly insert actions to database, and there is no requirements to data being processed from server2 before the save, you can choose option 1.
There will be no problems in the future, if you'd like to move database to separate service from server 2, because as for now it's already separated from the Parser.
Also, it's good practice to follow [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and keep service logic separated.
In your case it's better to handle all parse/save logic in parser module.
Just a note, if you'd like to process huge amount of data, for analytic purposes or something else, it would be faster to place script on the same server as your database, because you'll remove network latency

But, if you have some additional logic in your API.
For example, you'd like to notify users about updates via websockets.
It would be easier to implement logic with queues. 
Because parser would just send messages to queue and forget about them.
Then, your API on server2 would listen for messages and notify users about updates.
So, solution is to use remote database and if you have some additional requirements, use queues or Redis or gRPC or any other way to communicate services.

Additional links:

- [Redis pub/sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) could be useful in case you'd like to communicate. ([explanation](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/redis-pub-sub-how-does-it-work))
- [gRPC](https://grpc.io/), could be harder to implement, but nowadays it's popular :)
- And there is also [MongoDB steams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)

Comment: I also use redis and socket.io for sending notification and real time data display